# Scope_Identity not being returned as expected

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

Using entity Framework, vb and sql server.

I have a stored procedure (shown below) to insert a new record and return the new identity of the record concerned (the id column is a properly defined identity column).  The stored procedure is imported into my entity data model and called as a function, with the expected result being the identity of the new record.  However I always get 0 returned instead.

If I execute the stored procedure in ssms I get the result I'm expecting in the results window and also a separate result with the value of 0 (which is clearly what is being returned to my mapped stored procedure).

Either I have an error in my stored procedure, or I'm doing something wrong with the way that I call the function (also shown below).  I'd be really grateful for any suggestions that you might have to offer.

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Finances].[CreatePurchaseInvoicePayment]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@PurchaseInvoiceId int = NULL,
@SupplierId int = NULL,
@PurchaseInvoicePaymentDate date = NULL,
@Amount money = NULL,
@PaymentType int = NULL,
@ChequeNumber nchar(10) = NULL,
@BankAccountId int = NULL,
@purchaseInvoiceCreditNoteId int = NULL,
@ConversionFactor numeric(4,2) = NULL,
@ModifiedDate date = NULL,
@id int = NULL OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO Finances.PurchaseInvoicePayments
VALUES
(
@PurchaseInvoiceId,
@SupplierId,
@PurchaseInvoicePaymentDate,
@Amount,
@PaymentType,
@ChequeNumber,
@BankAccountId,
@purchaseInvoiceCreditNoteId,
@ConversionFactor,
@ModifiedDate
)
SET @id =  SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
END
```

which is being called like this:

```
Try
                pipId = CInt(te.CreatePurchaseInvoicePayment(pip.PurchaseInvoiceId, pip.SupplierId, pip.PurchaseInvoicePaymentDate, pip.Amount, pip.PaymentType, pip.ChequeNumber, pip.BankAccountId, pip.PurchaseInvoiceCreditNoteId, pip.ConversionFactor, pip.ModifiedDate,nothing).FirstOrDefault)
            Catch ex As Exception
```

As I say if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe function expects an actual resultset from the SP. In this case you don't need an output parameter, just add at the end of SP:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and the function should read it correctly.

Comment: Yuriy, the result is the same if I have just Select Scope_Identity.  The stored procedures returns both the identity (the bit I want) and a return  of 0 which is the bit that the function always seems to pick up, and the one bit I don't want.

Comment: Ok, it seem to pick the return value. Can you try at the end instead of `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` do a `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()` ?

Comment: Hi Yuriy.  I modified the procedure, declaring a variable id as an int and setting that to Scope_Identity at the end followed by Return id.  The sproc now returns only one thing (the identity) BUT interestingly when called from the function it still returns 0.  Now that has got me confused.

Comment: Something should work, and I suspect it's plain SELECT. Can you, in your VB.NET code do a simple test `dim testResult = te.CreatePurchaseInvoicePayment(...)` and examine the testResult in debugger?

Comment: Hi Yuriy.  Finally got a result, but not entirely sure why.  By declaring a variable of int, setting that to the value of scope_identity and then selecting as opposed to returning that variable I finally get back the identity.  In ssms the results pane still shows two results but this time the function just reads the returned variable.

Comment: From error messages in the debugger it appears to be something to do with not having enough columns returned.  Need to do some research into why its necessary to declare a variable and select that as opposed to simply selecting the scope identity in the first place, but at least I now have what I expected to have in the first place.

Comment: Really? "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTIY()" didn't work, but "SELECT @id" worked?